# Blocking outgoing SMS in Android. (except for default SMS app.)

Tags: android, android-intent

How can we generate the pop up if any app sending SMS?
I mean is there any way to block outgoing SMS through any app except default SMS app?

Any application can send SMS through android Phone with help of `SMSManager`. for example.

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();   
smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, "message", null, null);
```

I want to block such SMS sending process or generate a pop-up on phone that "xyz app is trying to send SMS .. Allow or dont allow..

Any help will be appreciable...

Comment: This is not possible, except via a custom ROM mod or *maybe* on a rooted device.

Comment: I have rooted Samsung S-III device.. can you please tell me how can we block the SMS sending..??

Comment: I do not know that it is possible to block outgoing SMS on a rooted device. This is the sort of thing that there might be trick for doing it on a rooted device, but it is not obvious to me what that trick is. That's why I emphasized the word "*maybe*" in my previous comment. The only way for certain to handle this is to do so in a modified version of Android itself, where `SmsManager` (or other things related to it) handle your blocking.

Comment: I know it is possible on rooted device.. I just want some way or guidance to do so.. thank you so much for your information.